# why else if not working here?

Tags: java, android, if-statement

When I will getIntent name for particular place my map will focus on that place but it's working for only one place, why is it so ? here is my code

```
 protected void onResume() {
    Thread timer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent intent = getIntent();
                        String restaurant_name = intent.getStringExtra("restaurant_name");
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, restaurant_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        if(restaurant_name != null ) {
                            if (restaurant_name.equals("Fun N Food")) {
                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(26.89209, 75.82759), 15.0f));
                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(new LatLng(26.89209, 75.82759))
                                        .title("FUN N FOOD"))
                                        .showInfoWindow();


                            }
                            else
                            if (restaurant_name.equals("Hoagies")) {
                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(26.89515, 75.83052), 15.0f));
                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(new LatLng(26.89515, 75.83052))
                                        .title("HOAGIES"))
                                        .showInfoWindow();


                            }
                            else
                            if (restaurant_name.equals("Ping Pang")) {
                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(26.89568, 75.83060), 15.0f));
                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(new LatLng(26.89568, 75.83060))
                                        .title("PING PANG"))
                                        .showInfoWindow();


                            }


                        }else {
                            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It was not", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }
                });
   /* Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, restaurant_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); */

            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();

    super.onResume();

}
```

Here only Fun n Food is working. Why all other two is not working what am doing wrong ? I try switch case also but in that none of one is working.

Comment: check the String in Logcat

Comment: Could you please format your question, as well as the code properly?

Comment: You need to debug and see what's happening.

Comment: not showing any thing there :/

Comment: could you print "restaurant_name" inside the your if condition, so that you can identify what string you are getting for all the scenarios...

Comment: May be your resturant_name is "Fun n Food".so it match with if condition and it does not go to any else-if.you should use debugging.

Comment: if it not showing anything and entering if condition means string is empty or it contains some string...not null...

Comment: "String restaurant_name = intent.getStringExtra("restaurant_name");" after this line put a log and print "restaurant_name" , u will get to know where u r wrong, while setting to intent or while comparing..

Answer (score 1):

Mistake is here : `else`

```
                `if` 
             it's actually like else is a single statement and if is a separate statement. So just remove the spaces and have `else if`
```

Replace with the below :

```
protected void onResume() {
    Thread timer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent intent = getIntent();
                        String restaurant_name = intent.getStringExtra("restaurant_name");
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, restaurant_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        if(restaurant_name != null ) {
                            if (restaurant_name.equals("Fun N Food")) {
                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(26.89209, 75.82759), 15.0f));
                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(new LatLng(26.89209, 75.82759))
                                        .title("FUN N FOOD"))
                                        .showInfoWindow();


                            }
                            else if (restaurant_name.equals("Hoagies")) {
                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(26.89515, 75.83052), 15.0f));
                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(new LatLng(26.89515, 75.83052))
                                        .title("HOAGIES"))
                                        .showInfoWindow();


                            }
                            else if (restaurant_name.equals("Ping Pang")) {
                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(26.89568, 75.83060), 15.0f));
                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(new LatLng(26.89568, 75.83060))
                                        .title("PING PANG"))
                                        .showInfoWindow();


                            }


                        }else {
                            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It was not", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }
                });
   /* Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, restaurant_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); */

            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();

    super.onResume();

}
```

Comment: Did you actually try? Line breaks don't seem to affect an `else if` statement. Besides with that logic if the restaurant is not "Fun N Food" the original code would anyway check if it's "Hoagies" and if it's not "Hoagies" the original code would check if it's "Ping Pang".

Comment: I just tried with sample codes. Its skipping the codes even if it's true.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, follow the structure of **if else** condition like

```
if(..)
{
   //todo
}
else
{
   if(..)
   {
       //todo
   }
   else
   {
      //todo
   }
}
```

or

```
if(..)
{
   //todo
}
else if(..)
{
   //todo
}
else
{
  //todo
}
```

Comment: sir its working now but only for two places when i try to put lots of places like lots of else if , if else then its not working again . i know my sounds silly but .. i don't know i am silly or a code :p but this thing its making me crazy

Answer (score 0):

```
if(restaurant_name != null ) {
                        if (restaurant_name.equals("Fun N Food")) {
                            //Todo
                        }
                        else if (restaurant_name.equals("Hoagies")) {
                            //Todo
                        }
                        else if (restaurant_name.equals("Ping Pang")) {     
                            //Todo                           
                        }
}
```